# Show that the measure $m(R) = \text{Area}(R)$ has more than one expansion on a specific set $S$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$\text{Let } X= [0,1] \times [0,1]  \text{ and define:}$

$S=\bigl\{R \text{ | } R=[0,1]\times[a,b] \text{ or } R=[a,b]\times[0,1]\bigl\}$

$\text{We define  the function on } S: m(R)=\text{Area}(R)$

$\text {Show that the measure } m \text { has more than one expansion.}$

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? Don't you mean $S=\{[0,1]\times[a,b]\mid 0\leq a\leq b\leq1\}\cup\{[a,b]\times[0,1]\mid 0\leq a\leq b\leq1\}$?

Comment: In which sense is $m$ is measure?

Comment: There is no additional information. I guess that $0 \leq a \leq b \leq 1$.
Plus, It said that m is semi-sigma additive.. then I guess what's important is just finding the expansions which are supposed to be measures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the question but I will try anyway to given an answer. Consider the map $\tau :[0,1] \to \mathbb R^{2}$ defined by $\tau (x)=(x,x)$ and let $\mu =m\circ \tau ^{-1}$, i.e. $\mu (E) =m\{x\in [0,1]:(x,x) \in E\}$.  Let $\nu $ be Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R^{2}$. Then both $\mu$ and $\nu $ assign the same value, ($b-a$), to the rectangles under consideration so there are multiple extensions.

Comment: So basically one expansion is the obvious and this is the lebesgue measure in R^2. The other one is actually the straight forward - taking the intersection between the unit square and the rectangle which contained in it?